# How to add a new instance variable to a class in ruby on rails using rubymine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I have created a class using scaffold in rubymine and did db migrate. Now I need to add one more instance variable (one more column to table in db) to the same class. How do I do this using rubymine (not from command-line) without destroying the class?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think I understand the real issue here.

Would you not just rollback the current migration modify the migration in `db/migrate` (N) and add the column you want, then update the views for the model (since you've used a scaffold)? Once you do that, you would migrate again. Either that, or you'd create a new migration that adds the column you want– however, given that you've obviously just started this app, I see no reason to add an additional migration simply for this.